# How to Lock a Check box when Clicked

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am trying to lock a check box when it is checked. So you can't un check it here is what i got. but its not seeming to work

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1 = True Then
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxe1.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not a typo? i.e.  `CheckBoxe1` has a rogue `e`

Comment: Yea 100% it is not a typo

Comment: Assuming your checkbox is an `ActiveX` checkbox then your code works for me on Excel 2010 i.e. I check the box and then it is disabled...

Answer (score 1):

Before you can disable a control that has the focus, you need to set the focus on some other control (another check box, a text field, or something else)

```
sub CheckBox1_Click()
    if CheckBox1 = True Then
        SomeOtherControl.setFocus
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False
    end if
end sub
```

Comment: SomeOtherControl would be what

Comment: I think he means you have another ActiveX control on the spreadsheet and you set the focus to that control.

Comment: Assuming the OP's point that the original code doesn't have a typo then they're not disabling the checkbox that they're checking.