# Excel tickbox and lock the cell

Tags: vba

Dears, 
I would need a code that does the following:
When I tick a checkbox it should freeze so that it is not possible to edit it, as long as password is typed in.

The checkbox is connected to a cell and a below macro is assigned to this:
Perhaps this would be added to already existing macro?

Thank you

```
Sub CheckBox_Date_Stamp()

Dim cbx As CheckBox

'Application.Caller returns the name of the CheckBox that called this macro
Set cbx = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)

'.TopLeftCell returns the cell address located at the top left corner of the cbx checkbox
With cbx.TopLeftCell
    'Check the checkbox status (checked or unchecked)
    If cbx.Value = xlOn Then
        ' Checkbox is Checked
        ' User Name and Date-Time
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = Environ("UserName")
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = Now
    Else
        ' Checkbox is unchecked; Clear cell contents?
        .Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        .Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Anyone could help?

Comment: Anyone could help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Lock a Check box when Clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860693/how-to-lock-a-check-box-when-clicked). In spite of info in that link, I am able to set Enabled property of another checkbox but not the one that has the code.